# Typewriter: generate variable name with appended postfix

Tags: typewriter

Currently I am using Typewriter for automatic generation of TypeScript class from my C# classes:

```
[TsDTO]
public class MyDto {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to simply generate a Typescript interface appending the postfix "xyz" to the properties names:

```
export Interface IMyDto {
    prop1xyz: string;
    prop2xyz: string;
}
```

Is is possible to define my template for adding "xyz" without creating a custom method?

This template does not work:

```
$Classes(c => HasAttribute(c.Attributes, "TsDTO"))[
    export interface I$Name {
        // properties
        $Properties()[$namexyz: $Type;    <-- "xyz" breaks the code!
        ]
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension method in a code block at the top of your template:

```
${
    string NameSuffixed(Property p)
    {
        return p.name + "xyz";
    }
}
```

Then use it in your Property template:

```
$Classes(c => HasAttribute(c.Attributes, "TsDTO"))[
    export interface I$Name {
        // properties
        $Properties()[$NameSuffixed: $Type;
        ]
    }]
```

Comment: it does not work :-( [$namexyz] generate the string "$namexyz". What I need is $name normally replaced with its value and "xyz" appended to the value

Comment: @GianpieroCaretti, That's odd, I thought I got it to work like that at one point. I updated my answer with another option.

Comment: I see now you said in your question "without creating a custom method". I'm not sure that it's possible.